# How to avoid com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing in Scala

Tags: scala, typesafe-config

I have a Scala project and I am reading config file to retrive value of constant from application.conf.

```
val config = ConfigFactory.load()

val param = config.getString("project.constant"+args(1))
```

Now if the constant is not present, then param should take a default value.

But the problem is if the constant is not present in application.conf,
it gives runtime exception `com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing` .

I have written a function

```
def isEmpty(x:String) = Option(x).forall(_.isEmpty)
```

so I can use isEmpty(param) to determine that if it is null, assign a default value.

But the runtime exception occurs at `config.getString()`.

Comment: I am looking for one property in the config, not the entire config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer, we can use the method hasPath() to determine if a given property is defined within a given config or not.

Comment: It's also perhaps more idiomatic to have a `reference.conf` file which sets the default value.